# SSRS "flatten" sql query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have data coming into a report (from a stored procedure I can't edit) in the following form:

```
RecordID |  Label | Value
1           Name    Alice Arnold
1           Addr    123 Main St
1           City    Hometown
1           State   US
2           Name    Bob Barker
2           Addr    456 Side St
2           City    Hometown
2           State   US
```

I need to display it like so:

```
Name            | Addr          | City      | State
Alice Arnold    | 123 Main St   | Hometown  | US
Bob Barker      | 456 Side St   | Hometown  | US
```

First, I tried grouping the table by Record ID, but I get 4 detail rows that are waterfalled.

Then I tried using an expression like:

`=IIF(Fields!Field_Label.Value = "Name", Fields!Field_Value.Value, Nothing)`

in the group header row, but whichever row happens to come first (Name, Addr, City, or State) is the one that shows up in the header row and the rest are blank because it only pulls in the FIRST record if you put detail data in the header row.

Any one have any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please tag with the *database* you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is non-database specific. It's an SSRS issue, not a database issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry I just saw that it accidentally got tagged with sql as well! My bad!

Comment: you could also try using Matrix instead of table. in that case you are leveraging report server to do the pivot vs sql server. Minimal overhead.